# How to print a vector of objects in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of the class Customer with data members like string for name that I'd like to print out. Using the cout << operator gives me the error "no operator "<<" matches these operands."

```
vector<Customer> customerVector;
Customer myCustomer(name);
customerVector.push_back(myCustomer);
cout << customerVector[0];
```

I've tried doing something like

```
cout << customerVector[0].getName;
```

but no luck so far.

Comment: Is `getName` a function? Then `cout << customerVector[0].getName();`.

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on printing the contents of the `Customer` class often it might make sense to overload the stream insertion operator.

This will allow you to achieve what you're looking for.

```
class Customer {
public:
    Customer( std::string name, int age )
        : name_{ std::move( name ) }
        , age_{ age }
    { } 

    friend std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const Customer& customer ) {
        os << "Name: " << customer.name_
           << " "
           << "Age: " << customer.age_;

        return os;
    }

private:    
    std::string name_;
    int age_;
};

int main( ) {
    Customer customer{ "Bill", 42 };
    std::cout << customer << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your object is written.

If your customer is like this:

```cpp
class cus
{
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        string getname(){return name};
        
};
```

then you can use `cout<<v[0].getname()`

or if your name is public , you can therefore easily use `cout<<v[0].name`